# How to have 2 different registration forms in one module in magento 2 (B2B, B2C)

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, registration, b2b

Trying to add different attributes to 2 different registration forms.

If anyone can advise where i can make this change please ? see below for the file structure that i Currently have:

```
1. module.xml

2. registration.php

3. InstallData.php

4. additional.phtml

5. customer_account_create.xml
```

If needed i can provide code within file, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You create your customer custom attribute in : `app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php` something like this :

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    /**
     * Install data
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

        /**
         * CustomerSetupFactory
         * @var CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        protected $customerSetupFactory;

        /**
         * $attributeSetFactory
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;

        /**
         * initiate object
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        )
        {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

        /**
         * install data method
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
         * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
         */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {

            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_phone', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile phone',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);
            //add attribute to attribute set
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_phone')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    /*use this mobile phone attribute in the all bellow forms*/
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout', 'checkout_register'],

                ]);

            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
```

Then your attribute will added in the register form via :

```
'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
```

If you want to update your form, you can do it in :

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

If you want it in a module, you need to rewrite in your module via `di.xml`

Comment: Hey @PЯINCƏ Thank you for getting back to me, i really appreciate it. i also believe that you have answered something similar to my question as well. ( i will throw in link at the end). my Installdata.php looks just like yours posted here. but how do i make it so i can control the two different forms and what they can have for registration? here is the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Hey @DevelopperMagento I know you had questions about this and the conversation with PЯINCƏ ended... would it be possible for you to help me justify this issue? Thank you in advance!